# Spring Transactional method exception never catch

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm begineer to Spring, in the spring transaction method couldnt catch the exception in catch block

```
@Path("/codes")
public class CodeFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Code> {

 @DELETE
 @Path("{id}")
 @Transactional
 public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) throws RestException {
    try {
        log.info("Removing Entity  ::"+id );
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // control never reach here
        log.error("Error ::: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RestException("Error ", e);
    }
  }
  //some other stuff
}
```

Super class is

```
 public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

 private Class<T> entityClass;

  public void remove(T entity)   {
        log.info("Deleting givne entity: " + entity);
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
  }

 }
```

springconfiguration applicationContext.xml is

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.esq.rest.service,com.esq.rest.exception" />
<bean class="com.esq.rest.exception.RestExceptionMapper" scope="singleton" />
<!-- REST service beans -->    
<bean class="com.esq.rest.service.CodeFacadeREST" />
```

In run time I can see the below exception in tomcat log

> Error Code: 20000
>   Call: DELETE FROM DICT.CODE WHERE (ID = ?)
>       bind => [1 parameter bound]
>   Query: DeleteObjectQuery(com.vrs.pojo.Code[ id=1 ])
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
>       at com.esq.rest.service.CodeFacadeREST$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9bec2548.remove()

However the same not being caught in the method try catch, I hope this is due to proxy. Is there any way to resolve this.

Edit :

I would like to catch and response it through exception mapper.

```
@Provider
public class RestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RestException> {
     // response user readable form
}
```

Comment: Since this exception is raised by the proxy, I don't think you can catch in the `CodeFacadeRest` class. But then I think you must be able to catch this exception in the caller of this method. And this class is the controller or entry point into the application, you may want to move this persistence logic to a new class (service) and call this servicefrom `CodeFacadeRest`.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu caller is typically a client, can be a browser. I need to represent error in proper format, see my edit.

Comment: So if this class is the controller or entry point into the application, you may want to move this persistence logic to a new class (service class) and call this service class from `CodeFacadeRest`. That way I think you should be able to catch exception and use your `ExceptionMapper`.